# R Why is paste replacing characters with digits?

Tags: r

In this given R code...

```
df1 <- c("a","b","a","b","b","c","b","c","c","d","c","d")
dim(df1) = c(4,3)
df1 <- as.data.frame(t(df1))

for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  df1[i,"paste"] <- paste(df1[i,!names(df1) %in% c("paste")],collapse="")
}
```

... I am expecting to see:

```
V1   V2   V3   V4   paste
a    b    a    b    abab
b    c    b    c    bcbc
c    d    c    d    cdcd
```

... but am instead seeing:

```
V1   V2   V3   V4   paste
a    b    a    b    1111
b    c    b    c    2222
c    d    c    d    3333
```

This seems trivial, and I do not understand what's wrong with code. Could anyone explain how my code is producing the given output?  Also, any other ideas on how to produce the simple output I desire?  Thanks.

Comment: `str(df1)` will show that these variables are factors, which more or less means they are integers with letters as labels. Use `df1 <- as.data.frame(t(df1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to have them remain characters when converted to data.frame variables.

Comment: `with(df1, paste0(V1, V2, V3, V4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `df1[i,!names(df1) %in% c("paste")]` returns a data frame. You can unlist the data frame in order for `paste` to work properly:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    df1[i,"paste"] <- paste(unlist(df1[i,!names(df1) %in% c("paste")]),collapse="")
#                           ^^^^^^
}

df1
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 paste
#1  a  b  a  b  abab
#2  b  c  b  c  bcbc
#3  c  d  c  d  cdcd
```

Here is how `paste` works on data frame if `df1` contains factor variable:

```
paste(df1[1:4], collapse = "")
# [1] "1:31:31:31:3"
```

As an alternative, this should also work for you:

```
df1$paste = do.call(paste0, df1[1:4])
```

Comment: This works great - thank you. I like the original, which makes no reference to the original columns names. (My question was generalized from a situation where I'm given a data frame, so "stringsAsFactors" won't work for me, or any code the refers to columns by name.  Your `unlist` solution is perfect).

Comment: One more alternative: `df1$paste <- sapply(df1,paste0,collapse="")` Edit: my bad, wrong idea

Comment: @Tensibai I think that pastes columns together instead of rows.

Comment: @Psidom indeed, I edited the comment as it could be of use for the OP (as he's using t() at first, he may be interested in saving this step)

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `unite()`, a convenience function to paste together multiple columns into one, from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
unite(df1, paste, V1:V4, sep = "", remove = FALSE)
```

Which gives:

```
#  paste V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  abab  a  b  a  b
#2  bcbc  b  c  b  c
#3  cdcd  c  d  c  d
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly more readable code using dplyr, with no for loop:

```
df1 %>%
 mutate(paste = paste0(V1,V2,V3,V4))
```